# Using Regexp to select the date from a string

Tags: strings, datetime, regex

I have a string with date details with time, but I would like to show the day information alone.  For that, I use the regexp to select the date.  Can anyone tell me the regexp, and if what is used is the correct one?

Here is my string:

```
2014-09-12T00:00:00
```

Here is the regexp, what is used:

```
\d.+\-\d{1,2}
```

I am getting the result as:

```
2014-09-12
```

I am getting correct result, but I am wondering if there may be a better approach.

Comment: The logical answer to this question is *"Do not use regex to parse a date, use the date library that comes with your language"*, but you do not provide enough context to even give the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression you used, although it works, it's not very specific. It matches the sequence of these:

- `\d` = a digit
- `.+` = one or more of *any* character
- `\-` = a literal `-` (btw you didn't need the `\` here, it has no effect here)
- `\d{1,2}` = one or two digits

Many non-dates can match this pattern too, for example these strings:

- `1abcdefg-4`
- `2999999!@$$#$@#$-12`
- ...

I would recommend to use a more strict pattern, for example:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

This matches the sequence of these:

- exactly 4 digits
- literal `-`
- exactly 2 digits
- literal `-`
- exactly 2 digits

Note that this is still not perfect. It won't prevent these invalid dates:

- `2014-02-31`
- `9999-99-99`

A bit more strict pattern would be:

```
2\d{3}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d
```

Which, of course, is still not perfect, because it will still allow `2014-19-39`, for example. It's possible to be even more strict, but whether it's worth it / necessary or not depends on your use case.